# what is the purpose of "non unique index"

Tags: sql

I don't really understand why the non-unique index is allowed at all. Consider for the index of a book, it does not make any sense that I have several same subtitles (title 1 --- page 10, title 1 --- page 40 ...). What I think is that the index should be unique so that I can find the data I want simply using the index.

Comment: Names in a phone book are non unique and a phone book is indexed by name

Comment: Imagine that you have a table message_received with the columns ID, sender, message, and you want to perform a query using the sender in the where clause. Your query would perform better if you have an index over the sender column, but this index must not be unique, because you can receive multiple messages from the same sender.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of non-unique indexes is to make queries more efficient.  The only use is performance.

They can be used in multiple ways; some of them are:

- Filtering rows based on the index.  For instance, get all customers in zip code 12345.
- Joining to another table.  Often foreign keys have indexes for this purpose.
- Ordering the result set.
- Facilitating aggregations.

Unique indexes add one more facilitate, which is guaranteeing data integrity.  However, the uniqueness has little to do with how indexes are used efficiently.